# Microsoft graph - adding an event to default calendar gives back "Resource could not be discovered." error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to build an app which add events to calendars of an organization users.

I have an azure accaunt which is an office365 accaunt also.

I get an access token with the help of this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

These are the params and end point which i use to get the token:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my_tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bmy_tenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

- grant_type - client_credentials
- client_secret - {the generated client secret}
- client_id - {the app client id}
- scope - https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

And I tired it out on this end-point: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my_user_object_id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bmy_user_object_id%7D) It seems the token is working correctly.

But when I try to add an event with this end-point: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my_user_object_id}/events](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7Bmy_user_object_id%7D/events) I get this error:

```
"error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-07-14T12:50:53",
            "request-id": "382c2807-2aa6-4b54-b686-55051f809e3b",
            "client-request-id": "382c2807-2aa6-4b54-b686-55051f809e3b"
        }
    }
```

I gave this premmissions and granted them:

- Calendars.Read Application
- Calendars.ReadWrite Application
- User.Read Delegated
- User.Read.All Application

Any idea what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

`POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events` is not a valid endpoint for adding an event to a user's calendar.

You have to use `POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events` for the default calendar.

Or for a specific calendar: `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}/events`.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: You are right, but after changing the api endpoint to POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events I still get the same error.

Comment: Can you try to **GET** a user's calendar events to check if this also fails?

Comment: Same error with this end point: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users/{user_object_id}/events

Comment: The problem then probably is that the user has no (or inactive) mailbox or no active license.

Comment: You wrote again that you have used `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_object_id}/events`. This is the **wrong** endpoint. Please use `GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events`.

Comment: It gives me the same error. The user whos ID I use in the request is my account so i am almost sure that the mailbox exsists and the license is active, but to be sure, how can i check that? When i use the userPrincipalName instead of the ID I get the following error: "Resource 'name_q-web.hu' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

Comment: When I use the beta version the error message is: "The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise."

Comment: You can [get a user mailbox settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to check if a user has an active mailbox.

You can also [list licenseDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-licensedetails?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get more information about the used license(s).

Comment: I get this when I ask for the licens `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{ID}/licenseDetails` => `{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('{ID}')/licenseDetails",
    "value": []
}`  I have an office365 family licens where my account is the master. If I try to add an event in the graph expoler it succeds. Maybe my access token is wrong, do I use the correct params (I wrote it in the question)? I am not sure that the scope is correct.